# Google Colab: CUDA SETUP: Setup Failed

Tags: artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, coda, apache-falcon

I was trying to "import bitsandbytes as bnb" in google collab but it always has an Error.

I tried to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9zv369Ggfk and used his Collab notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1IqL0ay04RwNNcn5R7HzhgBqZ2lPhHloh?usp=sharing however when trying to run the second step it always has a CODS error.